# Unable to create folder inside Android/data

Tags: android, android-external-storage

I'm facing a problem with creation of folder inside Android/data folder.
My code need to create folder, and copy a file from asset folder inside it.
This is my code:

```
private File getFileForShare(String filename) {
    try {
        String extStorageDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
        File folder = new File(extStorageDirectory, "/Android/data/" + context.getPackageName());
        if (!folder.exists()) {
            folder.mkdir();
        }
        AssetManager am = context.getAssets();
        InputStream inputStream = am.open("audio/" + filename);

        File f = new File(folder.getAbsolutePath(), filename);
        OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(f);
        byte buffer[] = new byte[1024];
        int length = 0;

        while ((length = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            outputStream.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }

        outputStream.close();
        inputStream.close();

        return f;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

I obtain a FileNotFoundException when i initialize OutputStream object.
Also, if i go to Android/data folder, no new folder with my app package name is created. 
Inside manifest i've set read and write storage permission. What's wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> What's wrong?

The proper way to get a directory that, for the primary device owner, resides under `Android/data/` on external storage, is just to call `getExternalFilesDir()` on an available `Context`. Replace:

```
    String extStorageDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
    File folder = new File(extStorageDirectory, "/Android/data/" + context.getPackageName());
```

with:

```
    File folder = context.getExternalFilesDir();
```