# Check if file exists or not? file.exists() return always false

Tags: java, android, file-exists

I have a problem checking if a file exists or not this is my simple code:

```
File myfile = new File ("SecretFile");

            if(myfile.exists(){

                TextView mytxt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
                mytxt.setText("Loaded successfully");

            }
            else{
                try {
                    myfile.createNewFile();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                TextView mytxt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
                mytxt.setText("Not loaded,reboot the application");
            }
```

I am doing a simple game and i need to check the first app run , because when the app runs it load all variables from files but on the first run there's no files so the app crashes.
I also have another question the File "SecretFile" where is located?
How can I create a file inside Android/data/com.mypackage.myapp/SecretFile ?

Comment: Add this permission `android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
File myfile = new File ("SecretFile");
```

That statement has no meaning on Android.

> I also have another question the File "SecretFile" where is located?

Nowhere. You are welcome to store your `SecretFile` on [internal storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/07/storage-situation-internal-storage.html) or [external storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html), but you must do so by creating a `File` object pointing to those locations (e.g., `File myfile = new File(getFilesDir(), "SecretFile");`).

> How can I create a file inside Android/data/com.mypackage.myapp/SecretFile ?

You can't. The closest match is to [use `getExternalFilesDir(null)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getExternalFilesDir(java.lang.String)) where I have `getFilesDir()` in my above code snippet, which would put your file in `Android/data/com.mypackage.myapp/files/SecretFile` on external storage. Also as Der Golem notes, you would need the `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission on API levels 4 through 18.

Comment: `your file in Android/data/com.mypackage.myapp/files/SecretFile`. That is a non existing path. It should be prepended by `/storage/0/` or something like that.

Comment: @greenapps: I am assuming that the OP is looking at external storage through a USB connection and was referring to the path as seen from there, and I was trying to stick to the same relative paths in my prose to simplify things for the OP. `getExternalFilesDir(null)` will handle setting the right location in terms of code. If you are examining external storage using something else (e.g., DDMS file explorer, **`adb shell`**), then yes, the paths that the OP and I cite would be underneath whatever the root is of external storage on that device or emulator.

Comment: Thanks @CommonsWare you helped me a lot! I'm new in java so i didn't know this ,also thanks to other users!

Comment: @ToastMan: "I'm new in java" -- just to be clear, the way Java code is executed on Android is a bit different than the way Java code would be executed on a PC. For example, `File myfile = new File ("SecretFile");` would be perfectly valid in your typical Java program for Windows. The difference here is that *Android* works a bit differently, and so you have to always create `File` objects off of some identified root location (e.g., `getFilesDir()`, `getExternalFilesDir(null)`).

Answer (score 1):

In creating file in android, you need to add path where you will create file. If you cannot fill its requirement, file will not be created.

That's the reason why ur return data is always false.

[This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28129647/unable-to-create-folder-inside-android-data) can help you.